# Loop through cells columns wise and store all the values in a single variable - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of values in a column which i need in a single variable.
Also i need to append a domain name to each cell value.

How can that be done? I have tried array and loops. confusing.

Comment: Please show us (a) an example of the input and expected output, and (2) the code you are currently struggling with. That makes it much easier for people to help you.

Comment: Hello alex,  the values are stored column wise in a cell.  for eg:  cell A1: abc cell B1: def. i want to loop and store all such values appending rrr.com to each value and separating them by ";"... No codes yet. not sure on how to do it. hence the question,.

Comment: Can you show an example of what the result should be e.g. `A1: abc` becomes `abc;rrr.com`?

Comment: no.. abc@rrr.com; def@rrr.com etc...

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example assuming your values are in column A:

```
Sub DomainNames()
    Dim cl As Range, var As String

    For Each cl In Range("A1:A" & Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row)
        var = var & cl & "@rrr.com; "
    Next cl

    Debug.Print var '~~> abc@rrr.com; def@rrr.com; etc...
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. but the range is not static and will depend on the rows existing in the sheet. will try. thank you again

Comment: Just updated the code so it figures out how many rows in column A

Comment: For i = 2 To Row
If ws.Cells(i, 2).Text <> "" Then
    For j = 2 To row1
        If InStr(1, ws1.Cells(j, 2).Text, ws.Cells(i, 2).Text, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            For k = 3 To 8
            ws.Cells(i, k).Value = ws1.Cells(j, k).Value
            Next k
        Exit For
        End If
    Next j
End If
Next i

Comment: i am trying to automatically paste values from 2nd sheet to 1st sheet, by just typing or pasting the values in the 2nd column of the 1st sheet which is the vlook up value in the 2nd sheet.. and the above code doesn't seem to work. help?

Comment: Can you post as a new question? It feels like a different problem to the one you had originally...